# How to improve this Spark pipeline?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose I am joining a few `Spark` data frames like that:

```
abcd = a.join(b, 'bid', 'inner')\
        .join(c, 'cid', 'inner')\
        .join(d, 'did', 'left')\
        .distinct() 
abcd.head() # takes 5-7 min.
```

The `head` invocation triggers the pipeline execution that takes 5-7 min. Does it have anything to do with those `joins` ? How would you make the pipeline faster ?

Comment: how about using `distinct` on table before joining them?

Comment: Did not try it yet. Thanks.

Comment: Each operation you use requires full shuffle, unless data is small enough to be broadcasted, which is expensive.

Comment: Try moving the highest count of records to last join.

Answer (score 1):

`head()` returns just one record.
You don't need `distinct()`, if you need just first record.
It might save you from expensive shuffle.

However, considering you have joins above, and resulted dataset is not sorted - there are no guarantees what record will be returned.

Comment: I am afraid it's not correct. `head()` returns more than one record.

Comment: Only if you pass parameter `n`. By default it should return 1 record.